# How to dynamically BLE advertise on ESP32 and reflect on flutter app

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

My ESP32-based custom-PCB BLE peripheral is advertising LiFP batteries dynamic physical values, such as current or SoC (State of Charge).

Basically, the code is as follows:

```
/// Returns the manufacturer data as a String
void Ble :: setAdvertisingManufacturerData(BLEAdvertisementData *advertisementData) {

    const float soc = battery.getSoc();
    log("Advertising Soc %d%%", soc);
    
    const char bytes[] = {
        (manCode>>8)&0xff, manCode&0xff,
        // SoC: 2 bytes | 0~2 bytes
        (soc>>8)&0xff, soc&0xff,

    };

    advertisementData->setManufacturerData(std::string(bytes, sizeof(bytes)));
}

/// Prepares the advertising manif data
void Ble :: advertise() {
    BLEAdvertisementData advertisementData;
    advertisementData.setFlags(0x6);
    
    setAdvertisingManufacturerData(&advertisementData);

    pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
    pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
    pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
    pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
    
    pAdvertising->setAdvertisementData(advertisementData);
    pAdvertising->start();
}

void Ble :: setup() {
    // == Start the advertising
    advertise();
}

/// Dynamically advertises every seconds
void Ble :: loop() {
    // == Dynamically advertise
    static unsigned lastAdvertised = 0;
    const unsigned now = millis();
    
    if (!lastAdvertised || now - lastAdvertised > 1000) {
        lastAdvertised = now;

        BLEAdvertisementData scanResponse;
        setAdvertisingManufacturerData(&scanResponse);
        pAdvertising->stop();
        pAdvertising->setScanResponseData(scanResponse);
        pAdvertising->start();
    }
}
```

So far so good. But from the Flutter app, the advertisement manufacturer data still shows SoC to be zero (aka the initial value) despite the evolving value I see in my ESP32 logs.

I probably made a mistake, any help welcome!

[UPDATE] With the nRF mobile app I get this:

[image]

And I see there are two sections with type 0x09: the first one is "empty" while the second has the right data.

Comment: To start troubleshooting, I would recommend using your smartphone and an app like [nRF-Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to see if the ESP32 transmits the data as you expect.

Comment: ... and while the Bluetooth SIG specifies the little-endian format for the manufacturer ID, you seem to use the big-endian format.

Comment: `manCode` constant is already in LE format hence the MSB/LSB layout.

Comment: As you can see, there is no "manufacturer-specific data" in the advertising data of your application. The code you show does not make much sense to me in relation to the problem you describe ( `advertise()` is never called, instead of `setAdvertisingData()` `setScanResponseData()` is called ) I would therefore recommend creating a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: The advertise() is called from the setup(). I did the code addition to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did that, that makes my advertising being dynamic.

I removed the `setScanResponseData()`and replaced by another call of `setAdvertisementData()` as I do in `advertise()`.

But I still don't get what `setScanResponseData()` is for.

```
void Ble :: loop() {

    // == Dynamically advertise
    static unsigned lastAdvertised = 0;
    const unsigned now = millis();

    if (!lastAdvertised || now - lastAdvertised > 5000) {
        lastAdvertised = now;
        
        log("Dynamic advertising");

        BLEAdvertisementData scanResponse;
        std::string md = getAdvertisingManufacturerData();
        setAdvertisingManufacturerData(md, &scanResponse);
        pAdvertising->stop();
        //pAdvertising->setScanResponseData(scanResponse);
        pAdvertising->setAdvertisementData(scanResponse);
        pAdvertising->start();

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this answers your question or solves your problem, but I'm glad if it works for you. By the way, the source code in your answer does not seem to match the one in your question. For example, the signature of setAdvertisingManufacturerData() in your answer does not match the function in your question.